# Leaflet. How I can get JSON marker property by Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: json, ajax, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I have my custom 'latitude' and 'longitude' variable.

```
var custom_loc = [50.34434, 63.23442]
```

And also I have `JSON` data with points in `GeoJSON` format.

```
 {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [50.34434, 63.23442]
  },
  "properties": {
    "id" : "1",
    "name": "Good place"
  }
}
```

How I can find `JSON` marker by `"custom_loc"` and get `JSON` property (for e.x. `"ID"`)?

I use leaflet.js in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a markers `getLatLng()` method to access its latlng and then match it with your custom location. To bind the id to the layer your best bet is to add the geoJSON feature to a L.GeoJSON layer and access the id via `layer.feature.properties.id` or bind the id to the layer via `onEachFeature` method passed into L.GeoJSON options.

Then whenever you want to find the layer with the matching latlng just loop through your geojson layer using the `eachlayer` method e.g.:

```
var custom_loc = [50.34434, 63.23442];
var geoJSON = L.geoJson(
      {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [50.34434, 63.23442]
          },
          "properties": {
            "id" : "1",
            "name": "Good place"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.options.id = feature.properties.id;
      }
    }
);
map.addLayer(geoJSON);

geoJSON.eachLayer(l => {
  var coords = l.feature.geometry.coordinates;
  var latlng = l.getLatLng();
  if (latlng.lat === custom_loc[1] && latlng.lng === custom_loc[0]) {
    console.log(`Latlng match: ${l.options.id}`)
  }
  if (coords[0] === custom_loc[0] && coords[1] === custom_loc[1]) {
    console.log(`Latlng match: ${l.options.id}`);
  }
});
```